# Finding context-free grammar

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, formal-languages

I've had quite a problem with this task:

```
L = {w element of {a,b}* | 
       the number of a's plus 2 times the number of b's modulo 5 in w is 0}
```

I thought about:

```
S -> ε

S -> abbS

S -> babS

S -> bbaS

S -> aaaaaS

S -> aaabS
```

etc...

But that can't be the optimal solution since you'd also have to shift the positions of the S and it would generate way too many cases. Also it would just be an enumeration of the cases rather then a "general solution" which is clearly not the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest introducing auxiliary non-terminal symbols:

- `M5` = `the number of a's plus 2 times the number of b's modulo 5 in w is 0`
- `M4` = `the number of a's plus 2 times the number of b's modulo 4 in w is 0`
- `M3` = `the number of a's plus 2 times the number of b's modulo 3 in w is 0`
- `M2` = `the number of a's plus 2 times the number of b's modulo 2 in w is 0`

Then the grammar can be expressed as follows:

```
S -> ε
S -> M5 S

M5 -> a M4
M5 -> M4 a
M5 -> b M3
M5 -> M3 b

M4 -> a M3
M4 -> M3 a
M4 -> b M2
M4 -> M2 b

M3 -> a M2
M3 -> M2 a
M3 -> b a
M3 -> a b

M2 -> a a
M2 -> b
```

Comment: This makes sense. What about words w where x=nr. of a+ 2* nr. of b and x = 10... 10 mod 5 is 0 as well and with your example I can't build abbbab (which would be in the language) or can I? .... Would S->M5S be the possible solution?

Comment: You're right, of course! 
I modified the start rule so that multiples of M5 are possible. 
Now: `abbbab <- abbb M3 <- abb M5 <- ab M2 M5 <- a M4 M5 <- M5 M5 = M5 M5 ε <- M5 M5 S <- M5 S <- S`